# Problem applying graduated symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm trying to display concentrations of bank lending by postcode in QGIS 3.12.3 Bucaresti, using a Mac 10.15.5

I've successfully joined my attribute only table to my postcode vector layer, and all the data is displayed correctly and in the right place when I open attribute table of the vector layer.

[image: Attribute table of postcode sector vector layer]

I've then gone into symbology, hit the £ sign, and used `to_int` to convert the text Q string of the lending data to integers.

[image: Graduated Symbology after hitting the £ sign]

But all the graduated classes display 0 - 0, no matter what I do.

[image]

I can see that the data is in the layer and ranges from *NULL*, to 0, to 10'000s, to millions. What makes this even more frustrating is I've done this exact process on a number of other layers and had no problem.

Can anyone help enlighten what I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong here please?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the issue?

Comment: try creating a new attribute with the int values in it - I suspect to_int doesn't like the `,`s

Comment: Hi Ian - thanks for your suggestion. You were exactly right, it didn't like the '000 seperators (the commas , )

Answer (score 3):

Reimporting the attribute table after removing the thousand seperators `,` removed the issue.